# Azure Media Services encoding process taking lot of time

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have been using Azure Media Services to upload files, encode them to multi-bitrate mp4 and then expose them as smooth streaming units using locators. My problem is that the encoding process is taking a lot of time, say 25-30 minutes for a 30MB file. The mp4 files that I will actually use will be much bigger and I suppose that would take time in hours.

Is there a way to speed up this process, using some other encoders or other means ?

Comment: Is all the time on processing state?

Answer (score 1):

What speed of Encoding units are you using?  Are you using just the free shared pool with no reserved units?

Take a look at the different sizes available (S1, S2, S3) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-scale-media-processing-overview#choosing-between-different-reserved-unit-types

S3 size units are the fastest.